# Aplicacion SignalR, Websockets no se reconecta despues de cierto tiempo

Tags: jquery, asp, signalr

Tengo una aplicacion la cual esta usando SignalR, para consultar notificaciones en Sql Server.

Todo funciona bien hasta cierto tiempo, he notado que en ocasiones trabaja bien hasta en un lapso de 1 hora, en otras ocasiones en menos tiempo.

Uso un timeSpan el cual tenia un tiempo cada segundo, lo que intente fue ampliar el tiempo, actualmente tiene 10 segundos.

Pero sigo teniendo el problema, al inspeccionar el documento, y en console, me aparecen estos mensajes:

[image: En color rojo aparece la ultima notificacion, y despues intenta reconectarse pero ahi ya no he podido solucionar esa parte]

Lo que intente applicar es usar lo siguiente para reconectar el protocolo cuando se desconecte, pero no se conecta otra vez.

```
  $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
  $.connection.hub.start();
  }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
  });
```

Comment: Que error te arroja la consola de ejecución de dotnet?

Comment: No me arroja ningun error, solamente se cicla como se muestra en la imagen en la parte inferior, se reconecta pero de ahi ya no recibo notificaciones.

Comment: ¿Desde qué entorno lo pruebas? ¿Desarrollo? ¿Staging? ¿Producción?

Comment: Desde produccion lo estoy checando.

Comment: Sigo checando los mensajes que muestra en consola, y ahora me manda el siguiente mensaje: KEEP ALIVE HAS BEN MISSED, CONNECTION MAY BE DEAD/SLOW. Aunque tengo mi funcion para reconectar me esta mandando este mensaje anterior